# Exception in array element swapping

Tags: java

I have this code to swap pairs of array elements:

```
int[] a= new int[]{1,2,3,4};
for(int i=0; i<a.length ;i++)
{
    int temp= a[i];
    a[i] = a[i+1];
    a[i+1] = temp;
}
```

However, I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at com.B.main(B.java:14)
```

Why am I getting this exception? How can I fix it?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++)

Comment: this code can throw two `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` 1) From for loop condition   `i < a.length`  while accessing a[i] 2) when condition  `i < a.length -1` while accessing a[i+1)

Answer (score 4):

Lets draw a table:

```
 i | a[i]
---+------
 0 |  1 :)
 1 |  2 :)
 2 |  3 :)
 3 |  4 :)
 4 |  ? :_(
```

Note that arrays are zero-based in Java, that means, if you have an array of size `N` (4 in your case), then the indexes are from `0` to `N - 1` (`0` to `3` in your case).

So when you try to access `a[a.length - 1 + 1]` (`a[i+1]` in the last iteration) you're getting [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the reason that you are accessing the element at `a.length` which is not available, so the code throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` so please use `a.length - 1` in the for loop. The problem in your case was at last iteration. You were trying to use a[4], but the elements in array a[ ] started from a[0] and ended at a[3].

Answer (score 0):

You are going upto `a.length - 1`

```
    for(int i=0; i<a.length ;i++)
```

and you are trying to access element at `a.length` which is out of bound

Answer (score 0):

You are starting from `i=0`. So it should be `a.length-1`